# AWS S3 NET6: how to create S3 client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I develop NET Core app working with S3. It works ok. I create S3 client using one of ways:
regional endpoint only - in this case used stored on my computer profile
accKey+secKey+regional endpoint - it works

My question is: I will provide my app to customers.
How they will use the app: with my keys or they should have a aws profile on every computer?

May be I need use acckey+secKey from app config and then customer can enter there its own keys?
How should I provide Lambda NET6 working with S3: keys?
What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way a user of your app would need to supply their own keys to run your .NET app. Its not the way AWS works. The app should always run using the keys **owned by the business**. As far as Lambda and .NET (or any SDK), AWS Lambda functions run using a configured IAM Role that has permission to invoke a given AWS Service.

For information about developing an app using .NET SDK that uses Lambda and invoking AWS Services, I recommend that you read the document linked below. Even better, follow it step by step to gain a deeper understanding of how all of these concepts work.

This document covers developing a Photo Asset Management (PAM) app that uses Amazon Rekognition to categorize images, which are stored with Amazon S3 Intelligent-Tiering for cost savings. Users can upload new images that are analyzed with label detection. Those labels are then stored in an Amazon DynamoDB table.

Users can later request a bundle of images associated with a list of labels. When images are requested, they are retrieved from Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), zipped, and the user is sent a link to download the resulting zip file.

[Create a photo asset management application with the SDK for .NET (v3)](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/cross-service/PhotoAssetManager)

Comment: Ok, the customer has users in Cognito which run Lambdas. One of Lambdas works with S3. I.e. client app->API Gateway->Lambda->RDS, ->S3. And my question about this way: what should I use inside of Lambda to create S3 Client?

Comment: This AWS app example shows how to create an S3 client and use it within a Lambda function created via . NET SDK.

Comment: If you follow the doc, you will find answers to your questions